# In @ Connect, it defaults to Mentions rather than Interactions

Tags: twitter

Is it possible to set Twitter to default to Interactions?

Every time I open the @Connect tab it shows the Mentions despite selecting the Interactions the previous time I opened the page.

Answer (score 3):

This is a recent change, as the @Connect tab previously defaulted to Interactions. Seems like it's something Twitter is experimenting with.

Unfortunately, there is currently no Twitter setting for selecting the default view for @Connect.

EDIT: Looks like the default is back to Interactions again.